# vuejs pwa prevent using cache when requesting /api/ routes

Tags: vue.js, caching, progressive-web-apps

i had created a Vuejs project with PWA support but when i am building its production build it always using cached version of api requests i want to prevent it from using cache for api requests or change its policy from being to cacheFirst to NetworkFirst for api i found a i had changed vue.config.js to prevent cacheing but its not working

```
pwa: {
    workboxOptions: {
        exclude: [/.*\/api\//,],
    },
},
```

any help on how i can either prevent cache on api routes or set networkFirst policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exclude` option only works for excluding precaching assets, which is what vue generates at build time, not api requests at run time.

It seems the `Cache-Control` problem of the api server, but if you do not have access to that server, you can config `NetworkFirst` policy `runtimeCaching`:

```js
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    workboxOptions: {
      runtimeCaching: [{
        urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://api.example.com/path'),
        handler: 'NetworkFirst',
      }]
    }
  }
};
```